# SQL: Pulling id's from one table to get names from another table

Tags: sql

Suppose I have two tables. One has hair color and user id.

```
TABLE A:

USER_ID   HAIR_COLOR
1         black
2         black
2         black
3         blonde
...
```

And another that has USER_ID and NAME:

```
TABLE B: 

USER_ID    NAME
1          John
2          Jane
3          Sally
```

I want to get a list of all users who have blonde hair in a single command. The catch is, I also only want users who are duplicated in Table A.

I'm new to SQL but I believe you can get all user_id's of people with blonde here who are duplicated with:

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    A
GROUP BY
    user_id, hair_color
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

But I'm lost on how to convert the list of user_ids into actual names via Table B. Thoughts?

(This is a trivial MWE, and I realize there would be much better ways of formatting the DBs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could trivially extend your query with a subquery:

```
SELECT
    user_id, (SELECT name FROM B WHERE B.user_id = A.user_id)
FROM
    A
GROUP BY
    user_id, hair_color
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I like how succinct and readable this is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (extending your query):

```
SELECT B.user_id, B.name
FROM B
WHERE B.user_id IN 
    ( SELECT
          user_id
      FROM
         A
      GROUP BY
          user_id, hair_color
      HAVING 
          COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```